# How to check all values in the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if 10 input fields are possitive number.
I want to show the user an alert msg when one of them is negative.

Do you have any good way of doing it with Jquery? the only thing i came up with was really long and disorder.

thx!

Comment: What way did you use?

Comment: Show us the code you have this far!

Comment: I didn't start writing it.
The only way i have in mind is to just check one by one with $('#input id').val()
But I'm sure there is a better way then that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your markup, I can only guess what you need exactly. This would work but might need some customization.

```
var errors = 0;
$('input').each(function() {
    if(isNaN($(this).val()*1) || $(this).val() < 0) {
        errors++;
    }
});
if(errors > 0) {
    alert('You have ' + errors + ' errors!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
if ($('input[value^="-"]').length > 0) {
    alert('You have a negative value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter`.

```
var chk = $('form').find("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value < 0;
});
if(chk.length) {
    // at least one is negative
}
```